# Continues sound/vibration alerts for local notification while iphone is closed, as it is done in clock app

Tags: ios4, alert, clock, localnotification

I wish to know how to generate local notification alerts similar to apple's clock alarm (that comes with the iPhone) while my application is the the background and/or the iPhone is closed.  Currently I gets a single vibration and a single play of my ringtone.  This is not sufficient and must run in loop till having user response.  So how the did it in Apple? TNX.

Answer (score 0):

They used private APIs that are not accessible to normal developers like you and I. The best you're going to get is that one ring and one vibration, unless you're not going for distribution in the App Store.

Comment: Are you familiar with workaround to solve this issue?  What is the problem with App store: they won't approve multiple alarms/vibration or the issue of using workaround to use their privet API's?  TNX

Comment: Private API usage is not allowed amongst developers wishing to publish their apps on the App Store.